# Difference between HF Communication and VHF Communication

Tags: microcontroller, communication

I am new to Radio Communication. I don't understand what was the challenge in establishing VHF Communication system w.r.to HF Communication System that made the former one to arrive later. (Talking as per the order of development of Aeronautical Communication System)

Comment: Clarify the question. There are practical differences between them, which still apply today, and historical differences which caused one to appear first, but are no longer relevant. The title suggests you want the practical differences, but the body asks about the historical differences. Which is it?

Comment: The key is in the name: "High Frequency". 3 MHz is "High"? Today that's a laugh, but back then... So >30 MHz was given the moniker "Very High"; >300 MHz "Ultra High"; >3 GHz "Super High"; >30 GHz "Extremely High"; and my favourite: >300 GHz "Tremendously High" (OK, OK, Terahertz...) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_spectrum.  Oh, and why orders of magnitude based on 3? The speed of light is 300 million meters per second...

Comment: Actually yes I am talking abt the historical difference !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the simplest level, the limitation was devices (vacuum tubes) that would operate at higher frequencies.  This evolution of communication technology to higher and higher frequencies continues even as you are reading this sentence. Few people dreamed 10 years ago that we would have inexpensive mass-market consumer gear that operates at 5GHz and higher.

Comment: Thankyou Very Much !! Sir       I got the perfect answer